# Thymeleaf - Only print row if (th:field is != null)

Tags: java, thymeleaf

I have two questions actually.

**1ª**: I have this input:

```
<div>
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="numEventsByPage" th:field="*{numEventsByPage}" /> 
</div>
```

This Id (*numEventsByPage*), can I use it globally or does it restrict only inside tha tag?

**2ª**: And, how do i print a row only if this field is !=null ?

For exemple:

```
<div th:if= "${numEventsByPage != 'null'}" >

            // print row...
            <div class="row">...</div>
```

I was trying the way of this exemple, but is was not working or returning any erros.
If anyone could direct me to a good tutorial or the answer itself, i would be veary grateful.

Comment: 'null' is a string. Check for null: ${ ... != null } and check for empty string: ${ .... != '' }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`th:field` is directly related to `th:object`.  Somewhere in your code you are defining a `th:object` like this (probably in a form tag).

```
<form th:object="${whatever} />
```

A th:field expression is equivalent in this way:

```
*{numEventsByPage} == ${whatever.numEventsByPage}
```

Notice that `whatever` must match your `th:object` definition.  You can also use the `#object` shortcut to refer to your `th:object`. So your options are:

```
<!-- Where whatever is your th:object -->
<div th:if= "${whatever.numEventsByPage != null}">
```

or

```
<div th:if= "${#object.numEventsByPage != null}">
```

Answer (score 0):

1.) Currently as per the code you Pasted here, it is being restricted to this input here only.
And Yes! you can use it Globally however By **'using it Globally'** I'm assuming that you want to put this object inside a JavaScript Global Variable. if that's the case use -

 Thymeleaf's **`<script th:inline="javascript">`** tag.'
**Also,** **alternatively** in order to get this value ,you can always use JQuery or JavaScript.

2.)To answer this question, try this :---

```
<div th:if="${numEventsByPage != ''}" >
```